# Behavior of a Semicolon after for Loop Declaration

Tags: for-loop

Most `for` loops have the syntax:

```
for(initializer; condition; incrementer) {
    // code
    // code
}
```

If theres only one line of code, it may follow this syntax:

```
for(initializer; condition; incrementer)
    // code
```

Or

```
for(initializer; condition; incrementer) // code
```

So, my question is, how does this,

```
for(initializer; condition; incrementer)
    ;
```

Or this,

```
for(initializer; condition; incrementer);
```

behave?  `;` is a valid statement in many programming languages. So, does `;` at the end of the for loop signify that the loop should keep looping with no statements to execute, or is the `;` considered the statement to execute and loops this `;` statement until the loop terminates?

Comment: yes, that's right only the looping constructs execute. Many people like me put the ';' on it's own line in attempt to make the empty loop more obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C-like languages (really the only place this makes sense), your second description is the correct one: the empty statement is executed as the loop body.